# Rails: Set multiple values for hidden_input_field using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails

I am using Rails 5 and trying to implement multiple delete functionality. Here is the form:

```
<%= form_tag destroy_multiple_scan_assets_path, method: :delete do %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :asset_ids, nil, multiple: true %>
  <%= submit_tag 'Delete', class: 'btn btn-danger' %>
<% end %>
```

Now the hidden field value is to be set using javascript based on some checked boxes:

```
$('input.btn-danger').click(function() {
  var selected_asset_elements = $('input.form-check-input:checkbox:checked');
  var selected_assets_count = selected_asset_elements.length

  if (selected_assets_count == 0) {
    alert('Please select an asset to delete.')
    return false;
  } else if (confirm(`Are you sure, you want to delete ${selected_assets_count} assets?`)) {
    selected_asset_elements.each(function () {
      // Push $(this).val() in to the hidden filed value
    });
  } else {
      return false
  }
});
```

How do I set hidden field's value so that it's interpreted by rails as:

```
Parameters: {"asset_ids"=>["1", "2", "3", "4"]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that using a single hidden field, but you can have that result if you add one hidden field with name `asset_ids[]` for each id. That's how rails knows it has to parse the params as an array.

```
selected_asset_elements.each(function (el) {
  field = document.createElement('INPUT');
  field.type = 'hidden';
  field.name = 'asset_ids[]';
  field.value = el.id; #something like this
  your_form.append(field);
});
```

By the way, `multiple` is not a valid option for a hidden field, it just accepts a string value.